# How does the Accio spell work?

Tags: harry-potter

I know it is used to summon things. But can the summoner only summon things that he own or is there a range within which it can summon anything or visualizing something that he doesn't own summons the thing.

Could Harry have '*Accio*'ed the horcruxes had he tried?

Comment: If memory serves me right, in the books, he tried to use/suggested Accio to Dumbledore on the horcrux in the lake - it did not work, because it was protected against that